# Safari freezes when receiving a Javascript alert message

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, safari, uploadify, alert

My question will sound very vague.

I've made a website, and whenever a jQuery function or one of my javascript functions are showing an 'alert' box, Safari freezes.

Is Safari or browsers in general freezing with an alert-box a well-known javascript issue?
Could a jQuery function be stuck in a loop because it waits for me to press 'OK'?

My page is in ASP classic, and by freezing, I mean that I can only close it with the task manager.

[EDIT]

What makes my Safari crash is Uploadify. And the original Uploadify demo on http://www.uploadify.com/demos/ crashes too on Safari, so I won't go any further with it.

So the chunk of code would be to:

- Go to this address with Safari - http://www.uploadify.com/demos/
- Upload two identical files big enough to let you the time to add the second before the first finishes
- An alert will popup, making crash your Safari

I'll write to Uploadify.

Comment: Include a short chunk of code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ this up!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the jsfiddle link! My question sucks, that's true. If there were known issues, it would have been a good future reference, but that's not the case.

Comment: It might be a reference for issues found with Safari and Uploadify. I've added the tag.